# Is Django already has a built-in microservice architecture?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, microservices, django-rest-auth, monolithic

I am working on a Django Project, but now it's going enormously large. I am thinking to convert it to microservice architecture but I found that Django also has a related architecture, apart from having a common database. So my question is, Is Django have a semi-microservice architecture built-in?

Comment: no, it does not have, though you can build microservice using Django and related python libs.